# IP intercom across two networks

Tags: networking, routing, ipv4, telephony

I need my 2N IP intercom to ring phones across two different networks.

NetworkA is 10.1.10.x and has a switch 
NetworkB is 17.148.17.x and has a switch

Someone said I should buy a router to connect the two networks but I’m not sure what I need to configure to do that. I don’t want people who connect to NetworkA to be assigned an IP address from NetworkB.

*It’s a hassle when you are trying to print and you could be on the wrong network*

I have an edgerouter-x as well.

Comment: Anytime you communicate across two “different” networks, a router is what makes that possible. How it works is fairly simple, but trying to explain what you need to configure to work for your network is difficult. Without more knowledge of your network topology and equipment it’s not possible to give you an exact answer. Are these business networks? How are they isolated physically? Do they have two different internet connections? Two different edge routers? Are they connected in any way now? Can you draw a network diagram?

Comment: So they are business networks, one network on the 2nd floor and 1 on the first. They have two different internet connections from two different providers. I bought an edge router x to connect the two. I tried bridging the ports on the router and i was able to successfully ping from each address BUT the problem is I’m getting assigned that NetworkB IP address when I plug in my computer on NetworkA. And I’m still trying to get that door phone to talk to each network